# Unix shell scripting, need assign the text files values to the sed command

Tags: shell, unix, sed

i was trying to add the lines from the text file to the sed command
**observered_list.txt**

```
Uncaught SlingException
cannot render resource
IncludeTag Error
Recursive invocation
Reference component error
```

i need it to be coded like the following

```
sed '/Uncaught SlingException\|cannot render resource\|IncludeTag Error\|Recursive invocation\|Reference component error/ d'
```

help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create a sed script and delete each pattern consecutively:

```
while read -r pattern; do
     printf "/%s/ d;\n" "$pattern"
done < observered_list.txt >> remove_patterns.sed

# now invoke sed on the file you want to modify
sed -f remove_patterns.sed file_to_clean
```

Alternatively you could construct the sed command like this:

```
pattern=
while read -r line; do
   pattern=$pattern'\|'$line
done < observered_list.txt
# strip of first and last \|
pattern=${pattern#\\\|}
pattern=${pattern%\\\|}
printf "sed '/%s/ d'\n" "$pattern"
# you still need to invoke the command, it's just printed
```

Comment: thanks for the update, this is what i expected, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` for that:

```
grep -vFf /file/with/patterns.txt /file/to/process.txt
```

Explanation:

```
-v excludes lines of process.txt which match one of the patterns from output
-F treats patterns in patterns.txt as fixed strings instead of regexes (looks like this is desired here)
-f reads patterns from patterns.txt
```

Check [`man grep`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html) for further information.